# plotable matrix - assign label to each column or for plt.legend (plt.plot)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Lets say I have computed a matrix which I would like to plot (xy, in the code), I would also like to be able name what is in effect each row of the matrix according to one of the array that went into building the matrix in the first place (i.e. x)

```py
x = 2**np.array([8, 9, 10, 11, 12])

y = np.array([0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.06, 0.09, 0.1, 0.17, 0.3,
                     0.5, 0.7, 1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40])

y = y[:, np.newaxis]

xy = x*y
plt.plot(xy, label=x)
plt.legend()
```

[image: code result]

As you can see in the example the python code prints all of the array into the legend (I know that this is expected from the code) but what I am looking for is the legend to read off

Blue - 256

Yellow - 512

Green -  1024

Red - 2048

Purple - 4096

Does anyone know a way to get this behaviour **WITHOUT** using a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself after some experimentation

```py
x = 2**np.array([8, 9, 10, 11, 12])

y = np.array([0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.06, 0.09, 0.1, 0.17, 0.3,
                     0.5, 0.7, 1, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40])

y = y[:, np.newaxis]

xy = x*y
plt.plot(xy)
plt.legend(x)
```